# Preencher um select de acordo com outro select com Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5, jsp

Eai pessoal, alguem pode me ajudar com esta lógica?

Seguinte estou preenchendo o um select Fabricante com os dados de um json usando o Jquery,
o problema é que não consigo pensar em uma forma de preencher o outro select Modelo de acordo com q eu seleciono na fabricante, sou novo nesse negócio de Jquery.

[image: Formulario]

Meu Json

```
0   
id  1
nome    "Ford"
modelo  
0   
id  1
nome    "mustang"
1   
id  2
nome    "fiesta"
2   
id  3
nome    "Ka"
1   
id  2
nome    "Fiat"
modelo  
0   
id  4
nome    "Uno"
1   
id  5
nome    "Cronos"
2   
id  6
nome    "Argo"
2   
id  3
nome    "chevrolet"
modelo  
0   
id  7
nome    "Camaro"
1   
id  8
nome    "Cruze"
2   
id  9
nome    "Onix"
```

[image]

Aqui esta código do meu form, Obviamente a lógica q desenvolvi abaixo não funciono, ela apenas preenche o select Fabricante mas n funciona no Modelo preciso de um norte de como prosseguir.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    Fabricante:
    <select name="fabricante" id="fabricante">
        <option>Selecione um fabricante</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br /> Modelo:
    <select name="modelo" id="modelo">

    </select>

    <script src="<c:url value="js/jquery.js"/>"></script>



    <script>
        $(document)
                .ready(
                        function() {

                            carregar_json('fabricante')

                            function carregar_json(id, id_modelo) {
                                var html = ""

                                $
                                        .getJSON(
                                                "http://localhost:8080/alucar/cadastroVeiculoJ",
                                                function(data) {

                                                    html += "<option>Selecione "
                                                            + id + "</option>";
                                                    console.log(data);
                                                    if (id == "fabricante"
                                                            && id_modelo == null) {
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                                            console
                                                                    .log(data[i].nome)
                                                            html += "<option value="+data[i].id+">"
                                                                    + data[i].nome
                                                                    + "</option>";
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                                                            if (data[i].id == id_modelo) {
                                                                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].modelo.length; j++) {
                                                                    html += "<option value="+data[i].modelo[j].id+">"
                                                                            + data[i].modelo[j].nome
                                                                            + "</option>"
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    $("#" + id).html(html);
                                                })

                            }

                            $(document).on("change", '#fabricante', function() {
                                var id_modelo = $(this).val();
                                if (id_modelo != null) {
                                    carregar_json("modelo", id_modelo);
                                }
                            })

                        })
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Man, eu tive vários problemas também quando tentava utilizar esse preenchimento em JSP, a JVM transforma sua página em JSP em uma servlet e isso parece que zoa o javascript inteiro.
O melhor a fazer é realizar a requisição na sua API novamente, enviando o ID do campo de fabricante, dessa forma você consegue carregar os modelos baseados no fabricante escolhido.
Algo como isso:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for='fabricante'>Fabricante</label>
    <select name='fabricante' id='fabricante'>
        <option>selecione um fabricante</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label for='modelos'>Modelos</label>
    <select name='modelos' id='modelos'>
        <option>selecione um modelo</option>
    
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json", function(dados) {
    if (!("erro" in dados)) {
      for(linha=0; linha < dados.length; linha++){
          $("#fabricante").append('<option value="'+dados[linha].id+'">'+dados[linha].name+'</option>');
      }
    } //end if.
    else {
      alert("Não foi possível carregar as marcas.");
    }
  });
  $("#fabricante").change(function(){  $.getJSON("http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/veiculos/"+$('#fabricante').val()+".json", function(dados) {
    if (!("erro" in dados)) {
      for(linha=0; linha < dados.length; linha++){
          $("#modelos").append('<option value="'+dados[linha].id+'">'+dados[linha].name+'</option>');
      }
    } //end if.
    else {
      alert("Não foi possível carregar as marcas.");
    }
  });
  });
});
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado,

Grande abraço.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela dica, funcionou certinho, vlw mesmo !!!!!!!